# Conflicting Node.js Installations for NativeScript

Tags: node.js, nativescript, homebrew

During the NativeScript installation, I (partially by accident) installed Node.js twice on my macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 - Now I believe I will have some conflict errors down the line.

I installed the latest LTS version of Node.js from https://nodejs.org and everything went fine.

Then, reading the NativeScript installation documentation further, it recommends to use Homebrew and then then install:

`brew install node@10`

Which I believe installed Node.js again and I got the warnings below.

I was wondering if someone might be able to recommend how to correct this (I certainly don't need two versions of Node.js running). I just really need to use NativeScript in the Homebrew environment which is recommended. Thanks!

````
==> Installing dependencies for node@10: icu4c
==> Installing node@10 dependency: icu4c
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/icu4c-64.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/02/02afdd6a472c31351e46a3b2a38c1c77354f0cc9199c3dbd7e06bc171b3638a2?__gda__=exp=1564186180~hmac=4a70d
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring icu4c-64.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2: 257 files, 69.5MB
==> Installing node@10
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node@10-10.16.0.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/d5/d598385086c33d21b9d28ed8ca4f4a6e3665a7a2c17d9aa244b13ca17d171176?__gda__=exp=1564186247~hmac=830c7
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring node@10-10.16.0.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
node@10 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have node@10 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find node@10 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/node@10/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/node@10/include"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0: 4,144 files, 49.3MB
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
==> Caveats
==> icu4c
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

==> node@10
node@10 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have node@10 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find node@10 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/node@10/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/node@10/include"```
````

Answer (score 0):

The last command that you ran has installed the node.js 10.16.0.
You can easily check which version of node.js you have at the moment:
`node -v`.
That means it'll override any previously installed node.js unless you used some node.js versions management tool like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).
Since you didn't mention that I assume that is not the case.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I believe I have two versions of node.js installed now - One in `/usr/local/opt/node@10/` and the other in `/usr`. That is my concern. Because isn't that what the message `node@10 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.` means?

Comment: Have you made sure that `node -v` prints you the right version?
If so you can rest assured you comply with NativeScript recommendations.